# Python variable that updates when another variable updates

Tags: python, variables

Let's say I have a text file and its path. I have a variable file_path that points to the file name. I then have this second variable called file_data which is the text of that file path. When I update the file_path, I also have to update file_data separately which is kind of tedious. Is there some code I can attach to allow me to update file_data when I change file_path?

Comment: Read about the combination of classes and properties. You can re-read the file when the `file_path` changes through its setter

Comment: Having things change unexpectedly in the background is a very bad programming paradigm.  @DeepSpace is right.  Create a `class MyData`.  Then, when you assign a new file name, the class can go read the data into a member.

Comment: The basic answer to your question is no, there's no way to automatically link variables.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm still not sure if it is a bad idea. I'm using this as part of a notebook so when I want to load an image and also extract metadata attached with that image, it would be easier to just change the path of the image and then load the rest.

Comment: Right.  That's exactly what classes are for.  You give it a new file name, and it updates its own state.

Comment: Do you have some code for this

Comment: I'd like something that is instance-less like static. So I could do file.path = "..." and then file.data changes